# How can I run SUIM examples which package Akka in a fat jar?

Tags: java, maven, akka, maven-shade-plugin

How can I run SUIM examples which package Akka in a fat jar?

Following the project's readme, I get the error below, to the effect that Akka configuration elements are missing.

I'm using Maven as a build tool. Several sites say I can [fix](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/akka/tickets/2634-akka-remote-prevents-application-from--shading--(standalone-jar-creation)-due-to-config-issues-in---?comment=183467573#/activity/ticket:) this problem by using the Maven shade plugin. Building with the shade plugin as recommended, I still get the same error. So I suppose I'm doing it wrong. Can someone spot what I'm missing - or point out what additional thing I need to be doing? I've added the shade plugin config below to the examples pom in the SUIM source code and rebuilt.

Naturally, I expect the author was able to run this, somehow without the shade plugin. So if there's a way to bypass that entirely, please let me know.

**Configuration**:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
      <shadedClassifierName>allinone</shadedClassifierName>
      <artifactSet>
        <includes>
          <include>*:*</include>
        </includes>
      </artifactSet>
      <filters>
        <filter>
          <artifact>*:*</artifact>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </filter>
      </filters>
  <transformers>
    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
      <resource>reference.conf</resource>
    </transformer>
    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
      <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
    </transformer>
    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
      <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
    </transformer>
    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
          <manifestEntries>
        <Main-Class>edu.cmu.lti.suim.examples.App</Main-Class>
      </manifestEntries>
    </transformer>
  </transformers>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

**Error**:

```
$ java -cp ./suim-examples/target/suim-examples-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar edu.cmu.lti.suim.examples.App local[2]
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka.remote.log-received-messages'
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:126)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:146)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:151)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:151)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:119)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:157)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getBoolean(SimpleConfig.java:167)
at akka.remote.RemoteSettings.<init>(RemoteSettings.scala:18)
at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.<init>(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:108)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:105)
at akka.actor.DynamicAccess$class.withErrorHandling(DynamicAccess.scala:72)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.withErrorHandling(DynamicAccess.scala:90)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:105)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:102)
at scala.Either.fold(Either.scala:96)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:102)
at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:549)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:111)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createFromSystemProperties(SparkEnv.scala:128)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:105)
at edu.cmu.lti.suim.examples.App$.main(App.scala:37)
at edu.cmu.lti.suim.examples.App.main(App.scala)
```

[SUIM](https://github.com/oaqa/suim) is a project blending Apache UIMA and Spark.